# react map es6 arrow function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code and it render nothing, I wonder where is my mistake, I did not see any error in the console.

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
   return {
     items:[1,2,3]
   }
   },
   renderItem(){
   this.state.items.map((item,i)=> <li key={i}>{item}</li>)
   },
   render(){
      return(
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem}
      </ul>
      )
   }
})

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/

Need advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to call your method with `()`:

```
  <ul>
    {this.renderItems()}
  </ul>
```

Secondly you need to return inside the method:

```
renderItems(){
    return this.state.items.map((item,i)=> <li key={i}>{item}</li>)
},
```

These are just vanilla Javascript class methods. There's nothing special React does here. You need to call methods and return values the same way you would with any Javascript code.

Comment: when u use return and call it again? but it worked, thanks! is there any self executing function for the renderItem?

Comment: If this is the right answer click the empty check mark next to left answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm stuck again Andy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865363/pass-index-from-function-to-function-in-react