# pass index from function to function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of item, and upon on click of the delete button the item will get removed. I know the steps to do it but I'm stuck on how can I pass the key to the dlt_item scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/1/

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
   return {
     items:[1,2,3]
   }
   },
   dlt_item(key){
   //how to get index/id here?
   },
   renderItem(){
   return this.state.items.map((item,i)=> <li key={i}>{item}
   &nbsp;
   <button>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dlt_item}>Delete</button>
   </li>
   )
   },
   render(){
      return(
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem()}
      </ul>
      )
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `this.dlt_item` as

```
<button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this, i)}>Delete</button>
```

and in your `dlt_item` function you can splice your state array from this index passed.

Code

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
   return {
     items:[1,2,3]
   }
   },
   dlt_item(key){
   console.log(key);
   this.state.items.splice(key, 1);
   this.setState({items: this.state.items});
   //how to get index/id here and do setState
   },
   renderItem(){
   return this.state.items.map((item,i)=> <li key={i}>{item}
   &nbsp;
   <button>Edit</button> 
   <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this, i)}>Delete</button>
   </li>
   )
   },
   render(){
      return(
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem()}
      </ul>
      )
   }
})

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/4/)**

Instead of splice you can use `filter` as

```
dlt_item(key){
   var items = this.state.items.filter(function(obj){
    return obj != (key + 1);


   });
   console.log(items);
   this.setState({items: items});
   //how to get index/id here and do setState
   },
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/11/)**

Comment: besides using splice, can u do something like filter?

Comment: How to operate on the key is your choice. splice is the easiest way I found. You can also filter out the data

Answer (score 0):

Use `.bind(this, yourKey)`

In your example:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  dlt_item(key){
    console.log(key);
  },
  renderItem(){
    return this.state.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this, item)}>Delete</button>
      </li>
    )
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same result could be to return a curried function from you `Component`

The method will take a value and wait for the event to be called before executing the action.

I prefer this way as I like to limit the javascript in JSX as much as possible.

```
dlt_item(key){
  // return the event listener
  return function(e) {
    // do something with the state
  }.bind(this) // bind the inner functions this to the Component
}
```

The when you want to call the function you can do it like this

```
<button onClick={this.dlt_item(i)}>Delete</button>
```

```js
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3]
     }
   },
   // this function will take your key
   dlt_item(key){
     // return the event listener
     return function(e) {
       this.setState({
         items: splice(this.state.items, key, 1)
       })
     }.bind(this)
   },
   renderItem(){
     return this.state.items.map((item,i)=>  (
       <li key={i}>{item}&nbsp;
         <button>Edit</button>
         <button onClick={this.dlt_item(i)}>Delete</button>
       </li>
     ))
   },
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})

// immutable splice helper function
const splice = (arr, index, count = 0, ...items) => {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...items,
    ...arr.slice(index + count)
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main id="app"></main>
```